# Клик за пределами элемента, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть выпадающий список, и по клику за пределами открытого списка, нужно чтобы этот список закрылся. Это работает, но если кликнуть по заголовку `title1` или `title2` открытого списка, то выпадающий список сначала закроется, потом снова откроется.
Как сделать, чтобы при клике по заголовку открытого списка, чтобы список только закрылся, и не открывался?

```js
var $wrap = $('.wrap');
$wrap.find('.title').on('click',function(e){
  var $this = $(e.target);
  $this.next('.dropdown').slideToggle(300);
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e){
  var $block = $(".dropdown");
  if (!$block.is(e.target) && $block.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $block.slideUp(300);
  }
})
```

```css
.wrap{
  display: flex;
}
.item{
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
.title{
  cursor:pointer;
}
.dropdown{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item item1">
    <span class="title">title1</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>text1</li>
        <li>text2</li>
        <li>text3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <span class="title">title2</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>text4</li>
        <li>text5</li>
        <li>text6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ecrwmpz7/

Comment: у вас события разные, в одном месте `click`, в другом `mouseup`, второе срабатывает раньше, то есть по сути у вас работает все так, как вы написали)

Comment: @ThisMan, а как исправить?

Comment: кто-то подскажет как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', Title);

function Title(e) {
  let $that = $(e.target);
  $that.attr('class') == 'title' ? $that.next('.dropdown').slideToggle(300) : setTimeout(Dead, 200);

  function Dead() {
    $('.dropdown').css('display') == 'block' ? $('.dropdown').slideUp(300) : false;
  }
};
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item item1">
    <span class="title">title1</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>text1</li>
        <li>text2</li>
        <li>text3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <span class="title">title2</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>text4</li>
        <li>text5</li>
        <li>text6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если вы хотите при клике на document скрывать со слайдом то можно использовать таймер, если слайд не обязателен то просто hide().

Comment: благодарю, но сейчас можно открыть сразу два списка, а нужно чтобы при открытии одного, другой скрывался

Comment: title2 не скрывается при клике вне списка

Comment: Второй пример сделал смотрите

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', Title);

function Title(e) {
  let $that = $(e.target);
  $that.attr('class') == 'title' ? $that.next('.dropdown').slideToggle(300) : $('.dropdown').slideToggle(300);
};
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item item1">
    <span class="title">title1</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>text1</li>
        <li>text2</li>
        <li>text3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item2">
    <span class="title">title2</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <ul>
        <li>text4</li>
        <li>text5</li>
        <li>text6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а вы проверяли? клик за пределами списка сейчас открывает два списка